# AWS Beanstalk: Cannot retrieve logs in degraded state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After some time of serving my app has died and gone to "degraded" state. I have no idea what happened because no one was using it. Maybe it was hibernated and did not wake up?

Now I am trying to check the logs but I am not able to do it. Requesting logs takes ages and from time to time I get timeouts. When I click Request logs (100 lines or full logs ) I get this message

```
Elastic Beanstalk is updating your environment.
To cancel this operation select Abort Current Operation from the Actions dropdown.
```

this takes some time and finally nothing happens. Moreover I cannot abort this operation as is written because:

```
Error

Could not abort the current environment operation for MY_APP_NAME: Environment named MY_ENV_NAME is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be pending deployment.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using SFTP and than accessing logs on server?